# How is the efficiency of an electric motor affected?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, electric-current

Consider that I'm having a motor (AC/DC) and the power switch is on and it's being supplied power and of course the motor is rotating.

Now, I continuously start switching off and on the power. For 1 sec, it's power off and then next second, I switch it back on; and then repeat this process.

My question is: Will the above scenario anyhow effect the efficiency or the general life-expectancy of that motor? Will the RPM be effected anyhow (and is there a formula to calculate it?)

Thanks if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly affects life expectancy and if do it continuously at right intervals you can even destroy the motor/generator in a matter of few minutes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_Generator_Test

When a motor/generator is connected to the grid it revolves in-phase with the grid. When you disconnect it, its frequency will change and its phase will drift away from phase of the grid. Now if you connect it back when it's in opposite phase several bad things happen. Voltage across the coil and therefore it current and the torque would be reversed, stressing the load and the motor/generator. Beating will also happen due to frequency difference.

If you do it randomly there would be random phase difference which means less damage.